# Moving borderless NSWindow fully covered with Web View

Tags: cocoa, webview, nswindow, macos

In my COCOA application I have implemented a custom borderless window. The content area of the Window is fully covered by a WebView. I want this borderless window to move when user clicks and drag mouse anywhere in the content area. I tried by overriding isMovableByWindowBackground but no use. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Calling -setMovableByWindowBackround:YES on the WebView and making the window textured might work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to make window movable by overriding NSWindow's sendEvent method.

Comment: @fz300 Could you please post your solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it.

```
#import "BorderlessWindow.h"


@implementation BorderlessWindow

@synthesize initialLocation;

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
            styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle
              backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                defer:(BOOL)deferCreation
{
if((self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect 
                                  styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask 
                              backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                defer:NO]))
{
    return self;
}

return nil;
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow
{
return YES;
}

- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder
{
return YES;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)animationResizeTime:(NSRect)newWindowFrame
{
return 0.1;
}

- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
if([theEvent type] == NSKeyDown)
{
    if([theEvent keyCode] == 36)
        return;
}

if([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDown)
    [self mouseDown:theEvent];
else if([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDragged)
    [self mouseDragged:theEvent];

[super sendEvent:theEvent];
}


- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{    
self.initialLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent 
{
NSRect screenVisibleFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame];
NSRect windowFrame = [self frame];
NSPoint newOrigin = windowFrame.origin;

NSPoint currentLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
if(initialLocation.y > windowFrame.size.height - 40)
{
    newOrigin.x += (currentLocation.x - initialLocation.x);
    newOrigin.y += (currentLocation.y - initialLocation.y);

    if ((newOrigin.y + windowFrame.size.height) > (screenVisibleFrame.origin.y + screenVisibleFrame.size.height))
    {
        newOrigin.y = screenVisibleFrame.origin.y + (screenVisibleFrame.size.height - windowFrame.size.height);
    }

    [self setFrameOrigin:newOrigin];
}
}


@end
```

And .h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface BorderlessWindow : NSWindow {
NSPoint initialLocation;
}

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
            styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle
              backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                defer:(BOOL)deferCreation;

 @property (assign) NSPoint initialLocation;

 @end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the top hit on Google...the provided approach didn't work for me as WKWebView intercepts the mouse events before they reach the window. I had to instead create a subclass of WKWebView and do the work there (h/t to [Apple's Photo Editor/WindowDraggableButton.swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PhotoEditor/Listings/Photo_Editor_WindowDraggableButton_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017384-Photo_Editor_WindowDraggableButton_swift-DontLinkElementID_22) example).

I use Xamarin, but the code is pretty simple...here are the important bits:

```cs
// How far from the top of the window you are allowed to grab the window
// to begin the drag...the title bar height, basically
public Int32 DraggableAreaHeight { get; set; } = 28;

public override void MouseDown(NSEvent theEvent)
{
    base.MouseDown(theEvent);

    var clickLocation = theEvent.LocationInWindow;
    var windowHeight = Window.Frame.Height;

    if (clickLocation.Y > (windowHeight - DraggableAreaHeight))
        _dragShouldRepositionWindow = true;
}

public override void MouseUp(NSEvent theEvent)
{
    base.MouseUp(theEvent);
    _dragShouldRepositionWindow = false;
}

public override void MouseDragged(NSEvent theEvent)
{
    base.MouseDragged(theEvent);
    if (_dragShouldRepositionWindow)
    {
        this.Window.PerformWindowDrag(theEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man this works perfectly! Thanks. I'll add an ObjC implementation as well to this question, but this was is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

@starkos porvided the correct answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987061/140927 The following is just the ObjC implementation in a subclass of WKWebView:

```
BOOL _dragShouldRepositionWindow = NO;

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super mouseDown:event];
    NSPoint loc = event.locationInWindow;
    CGFloat height = self.window.frame.size.height;
    if (loc.y > height - 28) {
        _dragShouldRepositionWindow = YES;
    }
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super mouseUp:event];
    _dragShouldRepositionWindow = NO;
}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super mouseDragged:event];
    if (_dragShouldRepositionWindow) {
        [self.window performWindowDragWithEvent:event];
    }
}
```

For further info about how to manipulate the title bar, see https://github.com/lukakerr/NSWindowStyles